# Positioning issues while animating CSS & anime.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, position, anime.js

I am currently trying to design an animation for a frontend. I am using react, anime.js & css. The initial positonings are absolute. When a certain point is passed, the elements become fixed and should then be animated. However, I can't get the elements to animate so that they end up centered in a fixed header. Somehow I don't get on here for a long time and am already so stiff in my head that a few opinions and tips would be very helpful. Many thanks already!

The code for the calculation is in the `useEffect` in which `animation.current` is set. The initial styles were set with tailwind.

Initial position of the page
[image: Init pos]

Result position after scrolling down
[image: Final pos]

```js
"use client"

import anime from "animejs";
import {
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useLayoutEffect,
} from "react";
import { Artist } from "@/types/spotify";
import Image from "next/image";
import { convertRemToPixels } from "@common/layout";

export const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([0, 0]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateSize = () => {
      setSize([document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
    updateSize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
  }, []);

  return size;
}

export const useSticky = (ref: HTMLElement | null, offsetTop: string) => {
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(false);

  const scrollCB = useCallback(() => {
    const stickyElement = ref;

    if (!stickyElement) {
      return;
    }

    if (stickyElement) {
      let offset = parseFloat(offsetTop.replace("px", ""));

      if (offsetTop.endsWith('rem')) {
        offset = convertRemToPixels(parseFloat(offsetTop.replace("rem", "")));
      }

      if (window.scrollY >= offset) {
        setIsSticky(true);
      } else {
        setIsSticky(false);
      }
    }
  }, [offsetTop, ref])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCB);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollCB);
  }, [scrollCB]);

  return isSticky
}

export const getAbsoluteValueForClientWidthPercentage = (
  widht: number,
  pct: number
): number => {
  return widht * pct;
};

export const getAbsoluteValueForClientHeightPercentage = (
  height: number,
  pct: number
): number => {
  return height * pct;
};

export const getOffsetTop = (el: HTMLElement | null): number => {
  if (!el) {
    return 0;
  }
  const scrollTop = window.scrollY ?? document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollTop;
};

export const scrollPercent = (
  target: HTMLElement | null,
  duration: number
): number => {
  if (!target) return 0;

  const fullOffset = getOffsetTop(target); // Already scrolled + top of target
  const offsetEnd = fullOffset + duration;
  const relativeOffset = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const h = target.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  const bodyST = document.body.scrollTop;
  const docST = window.scrollY ?? document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  // Scroll value is negative
  // Offset possibly not yet over-scrolled
  if (docST + bodyST - fullOffset < 0) return 0;

  if (docST + bodyST - fullOffset > offsetEnd) return 100;

  const pct = ((docST + bodyST - fullOffset) / (offsetEnd - ((docST + bodyST - relativeOffset)) + h)) * 100;

  return Math.min(Math.abs(pct), 100);
};

export type Props = {
  artistName: string;
  opener: string;
  artist: Artist
}

export const Header = ({ artistName, opener, artist }: Props) => {
  const animationTriggerElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const headingElement = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);
  const imageElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const isInitiated = useRef(false);

  const [headerElement, setHeaderElement] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [headerInitialRect, setHeaderInitialRect] = useState<DOMRect | null>(null);
  const [headingInitialRect, setHeadingInitialRect] = useState<DOMRect | null>(null);
  const [imgInitialRect, setImgInitialRect] = useState<DOMRect | null>(null);

  const isHeadingSticky = useSticky(headingElement.current, "1.5rem")
  const isImgSticky = useSticky(imageElement.current, "1.5rem")

  const [scrollValue, setScrollValue] = useState(0);

  const [textH1Offset, setTextH1Offset] = useState("10%");
  const [imgOffset, setImgOffset] = useState("30%");

  const animation = useRef<anime.AnimeTimelineInstance>();
  const wiggleAnimation = useRef<anime.AnimeInstance>();

  const [ww, wh] = useWindowSize();

  const [pixelDuration, setPixelDuration] = useState(1000);

  const headerElementRef = useCallback((node: any) => {
    if (node !== null)
      setHeaderElement(node);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPixelDuration(wh * 0.95);
  }, [wh])

  const animationCallback = useCallback(() => {
    if (!animationTriggerElement.current) return;

    const scrollProgress = scrollPercent(animationTriggerElement.current, pixelDuration) / 100;

    if (animation.current !== undefined)
      animation.current.seek(scrollProgress * animation.current.duration);

    if (headingElement.current === null || imageElement.current === null) return;

    if (scrollProgress > 0 && scrollProgress < 1) {
      setTextH1Offset("calc(10% - 1.5rem)");
      setImgOffset("calc(30% - 1.5rem)")
    } else if (scrollProgress <= 0) {
      setTextH1Offset("calc(10%)");
      setImgOffset("calc(30%)")
    } else if (scrollProgress >= 1) {
      // TODO some header opts
    }
  }, [pixelDuration]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const val = window.scrollY;

    if (val > 0) {
      setScrollValue(val);
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollValue > 0) {
      window.scrollTo({ top: scrollValue, behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }, [scrollValue]);


  // Set base heights for later use
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitiated.current) return;

    if (headerElement === null) return;

    if (imageElement.current === null || headingElement.current === null)
      throw new Error("Null error");

    setHeaderInitialRect(headerElement.getBoundingClientRect());
    setHeadingInitialRect(headingElement.current.getBoundingClientRect());
    setImgInitialRect(imageElement.current.getBoundingClientRect());

    isInitiated.current = true;

    console.log("T " + headingElement.current.getBoundingClientRect().top + " " + imageElement.current.getBoundingClientRect().top)
    console.log("H " + headingElement.current.getBoundingClientRect().height + " " + imageElement.current.getBoundingClientRect().height)
  }, [headerElement]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (headerInitialRect === null || headingInitialRect === null || imgInitialRect === null) return;

    animation.current = anime
      .timeline({
        autoplay: false,
        duration: 100,
        easing: "easeInOutCubic",
      })
      .add(
        {
          targets: headingElement.current,
          translateY: [
            "0",
            `calc(-${headingInitialRect.height * 0.5}px - ${getAbsoluteValueForClientHeightPercentage(wh, 0.05)}px + ${headerInitialRect.height / 2 - (headingInitialRect.height / 2) * 0.5}px + 1.5rem)`,
          ],
          translateX: [
            "-50%",
            `calc(0% - ${getAbsoluteValueForClientWidthPercentage(ww, 0.5)}px - ${headingInitialRect.height * 0.5}px)`,
          ],
          scale: [1, 0.5],
          easing: "easeInOutCubic",
          autoplay: false,
          duration: 600,
        },
        0
      )
      .add(
        {
          targets: imageElement.current,
          translateY: [
            "0",
            // TODO: Fix values here they are currently kind of random
            `calc(-${imgInitialRect.height * 0.2}px - ${getAbsoluteValueForClientHeightPercentage(wh, 0.3)}px - ${headerInitialRect.height / 2 - (imgInitialRect.height / 2) * 0.2}px + 1.5rem)`,
          ],
          translateX: [
            "50%",
            `calc(0% + ${imgInitialRect.height * 0.2}px + ${getAbsoluteValueForClientWidthPercentage(ww, 0.5)}px)`,
          ],
          scale: [1, 0.2],
          easing: "easeInOutCubic",
          autoplay: false,
          duration: 600,
        },
        50
      );
  }, [ww, wh, headerInitialRect, headingInitialRect, imgInitialRect]);

  useEffect(() => {
    wiggleAnimation.current = anime({
      targets: imageElement.current?.firstChild,
      keyframes: [
        { translateX: 20 },
        { translateX: -20 },
        { translateX: 20 },
        { translateX: -20 },
        { translateX: 20 },
        { translateX: -20 },
        { translateX: 0 },
      ],
      duration: 500,
      easing: "easeInOutCubic",
      autoplay: false
    });
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", animationCallback);
    setTimeout(() => animationCallback(), 1);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", animationCallback);
  }, [animationCallback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", animationCallback);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", animationCallback);
  }, [animationCallback]);

  const onSticky = useCallback((isSticky: boolean) => {
    if (headerElement === null) {
      return;
    }

    const headerEl = headerElement.querySelector("#sticky-main-header-wrapper")

    if (headerEl === null) {
      console.log("headerEl is null")
      return;
    }


    if (isSticky) {
      headerEl.classList.remove("rounded-t-2xl");
    } else {
      headerEl.classList.add("rounded-t-2xl");
    }
  }, [headerElement]);

  const onEnterAvatarWiggle = () => {
    if (imageElement.current === null) return;

    if (wiggleAnimation.current !== undefined)
      wiggleAnimation.current.play();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!headingElement.current) return;

    if (isHeadingSticky) {
      headingElement.current.classList.add("fixed");
      headingElement.current.classList.remove("absolute");
      headingElement.current.style.top = "5%";
    } else {
      headingElement.current.classList.add("absolute");
      headingElement.current.classList.remove("fixed");
      headingElement.current.style.top = "";
    }
  }, [isHeadingSticky])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!imageElement.current) return;

    if (isImgSticky) {
      imageElement.current.classList.add("fixed");
      imageElement.current.classList.remove("absolute");
      imageElement.current.style.top = "25%";
    } else {
      imageElement.current.classList.add("absolute");
      imageElement.current.classList.remove("fixed");
      imageElement.current.style.top = "";
    }
  }, [isImgSticky])

  return (
    <section className="bg-gradient-main min-h-[90vh] w-full rounded-2xl">
      <div
        className="targetPoint h-1 width-full bg-transparent absolute top-[calc(5%_-_1.5rem)] left-0 right-0 z-modal"
        ref={animationTriggerElement}
      />
      <StickyElement ref={headerElementRef} stickyCB={onSticky}>
        <div className="h-20 z-10 w-full transition-border-radius rounded-t-2xl rounded-b-2xl bg-gradient-main" id="sticky-main-header-wrapper" />
      </StickyElement>
      <h1 className="text-5xl xxs:text-6xl xs:text-7xl sm:text-8xl font-bold text-center text tracking-widest absolute left-[50%] w-fit z-[21] -translate-x-[50%] top-[calc(10%)] w-[calc(100%_-_3rem)" id="artist-main-heading" ref={headingElement}>{artistName}</h1>
      <div ref={imageElement} className="absolute top-[calc(30%)] right-[50%] translate-x-[50%] z-20 h-56 w-56 xs:h-80 xs:w-80">
        <a href={artist.external_urls.spotify} target="_blank" referrerPolicy="no-referrer">
          <Image id="artist-main-image" src={artist.images[0].url} alt={artist.name} fill className="rounded-[50%] object-cover border-4 border-blue-300 shadow-material-4" onPointerEnter={onEnterAvatarWiggle} />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h2 className="text-xl xs:text-2xl absolute top-[80%] left-[50%] -translate-x-[50%] italic text-center tracking-wide w-[calc(100%_-_3rem)]">{opener}</h2>
    </section>
  );
};
```